# Webpack doesn't place images in dist folder

Tags: image, webpack, pug-loader

I have a pug mixin. Mixin is using to create block with whatever image name passed as argument.

```
mixin img({imageSrc: ""} = {})
  .img(src="./img/" + imageSrc + ".jpg")
```

As a result I want webpack either place this image in `dist/img/` or processed and replaced this path with it's base64 format.

Due to my need **to save relative paths** in sass and pug I use `url-loader`. So my current configuration for pug and image looks like this:

```js
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.pug$/,
    loader: 'pug-loader
  }, {
    test: /\.(jp(e*)g|png|svg)$/,
    use: [{
      loader: "url-loader",
      options: {
        outputPath: "images/"
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

Appreciate your help because I'm running out of ideas :c

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `url-loader` has an `outputPath` option, it just outputs to your Webpack config's `output.path`. Assuming that your `output.path` is `dist` (default) you can have files go to `dist/img` by specifying the `name` option like:

```
options: {
  name: 'img/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
}
```

Comment: agree...It's better to use file loader